# Android Source: Which class(es) turn(s) raw touch input or mouse input into actual input / navigation?

Tags: android-source

...As I need to modify the source to implement similar control using a gamepad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [MotionEvent](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.2.2_r1/core/java/android/view/MotionEvent.java) class and a [KeyEvent](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.2.2_r1/core/java/android/view/KeyEvent.java) class describing many kinds of user input events in Android. And the [InputManagerService](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.2.2_r1/services/java/com/android/server/input/InputManagerService.java) will take care of generating these events.

For example, if I need to generate a swipe event to android. I can simply get an MotionEvent and then inject it to android by InputManagerService.

```
MotionEvent event = MotionEvent.obtain(when, when, action, x, y, pressure, DEFAULT_SIZE,DEFAULT_META_STATE, DEFAULT_PRECISION_X, DEFAULT_PRECISION_Y, DEFAULT_DEVICE_ID,DEFAULT_EDGE_FLAGS);
event.setSource(inputSource);
InputManager.getInstance().injectInputEvent(event,InputManager.INJECT_INPUT_EVENT_MODE_WAIT_FOR_FINISH);
```

Actually I get this source code from [Input.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.2.2_r1/cmds/input/src/com/android/commands/input/Input.java), it also shows other examples on how to inject user input to Android.

Then move our eyes on InputManagerService. The injectInputEvent is a native method, and it finally rely on [InputDispatcher](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.2.2_r1/services/input/InputDispatcher.cpp) to enqueue the events and dispatch them. And then it will create a pipe called [InputChannel](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.2.2_r1/core/java/android/view/InputChannel.java) between Window and InputManager to dispatch the event to the target window.

Comment: injectInputEvent() is something that is available to platform apps only as they get built as part of AOSP code. The api is hidden from sdk apps because of security reasons.